# Java - trying to print a get method of an object from within the main method when object was created from another method

Tags: java, scope

I've already looked at all of the other stackoverflow questions on accessing an instance of an object from the main method and nothing I've tried has worked, I still continue to get the following error message

```
java.59: error: cannot find symbol
        System.out.println(student2.getStudentId());
```

here is my main method trimmed down:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Testing { 

  public static void main (String [] args) throws IOException {


  final String INPUT_FILE  = "c:\\Users\\XXXXXX\\Documents\\Input01.txt"; 
  Scanner br = new Scanner(new File(INPUT_FILE));  

// Test 2 - Test first and second line of information from input file

  String[] strArray;
  while (br.hasNext()) {
  strArray = br.nextLine().split(",");
     if(strArray[0].equals("STUDENT")) {
        processStudentData(strArray);
        System.out.println(student2.getStudentId());
     }
     else
     if(strArray[0].equals("GRADE ITEM")) {
        processGradeItemData(strArray);
     }

  }

  } //end main

// ***************************************************************

// Uses string array from input file to create new student object
public static void processStudentData(String[] a) {

  System.out.println("Running Test 2a:");
  if (a[1].equals("ADD")) {
     Student student2 = new Student(a[2], a[3], a[4], a[5]);
  }

} // End processStudentData 

} //end Testing
```

here is my Student class trimmed down:

```
public class Student {  

private String studentId;           // Unique ID for each Student
private String studentFirstName;    // Student's legal first name
private String studentLastName;     // Student's legal last name
private String studentEmail;        // Student's school email address

//************************************************************************

  Student() {

  } // end Student

//************************************************************************

  public Student(String studentId, String studentFirstName, String studentLastName, 
                  String studentEmail) {

     if (studentId.equals("")) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Student ID cannot be blank.");
     }
     if (studentFirstName.equals("")) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Student first name cannot be blank.");
     }
     if (studentLastName.equals("")) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Student last name cannot be blank.");
     }
     if (studentEmail.equals("")) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Student email cannot be blank.");
     }
     if (!studentEmail.contains("@")) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Student email must have '@'.");
     }

     this.studentId = studentId;
     this.studentFirstName = studentFirstName;
     this.studentLastName = studentLastName;
     this.studentEmail = studentEmail;

  } // end Student

//************************************************************************

public String getStudentId() {

  return studentId;

} // end getStudentId
```

I need to be able to print out the student information using my get methods from the main method yet still instantiate the student2 object through the processStudentData method. I do not want to have to change my get method to static as there will be multiple instances.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

UPDATE: I've added in a return to the processStudentData method and am still recieving the same error as before (main method has not changed, processStudentData method updated below):

```
public static Student processStudentData(String[] a){
  System.out.println("Running Test 2a:"); 
  if (a[1].equals("ADD")) {
     Student student2 = new Student(a[2], a[3], a[4], a[5]);     
     return student2;
  }  
  return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `student2` is defined as a local variable within the `if` statement of the `processStudentData`, it can only be used within that context (to which it is defined)

```
// Uses string array from input file to create new student object
public static void processStudentData(String[] a) {

  System.out.println("Running Test 2a:");
  if (a[1].equals("ADD")) {
     Student student2 = new Student(a[2], a[3], a[4], a[5]);
  }

} // End processStudentData
```

"A" solution would be to return the result to the caller...

```
// Uses string array from input file to create new student object
public static Student processStudentData(String[] a) {

  System.out.println("Running Test 2a:");
  if (a[1].equals("ADD")) {
     return new Student(a[2], a[3], a[4], a[5]);
  }

  return null;

} // End processStudentData
```

Then you could use it something like...

```
Student student = processStudentData(strArray);
if (student != null) {
    System.out.println(student.getStudentId());
}
```

You might want to take a closer look at:

- [Language Basics/Variables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html)
- [Returning a Value from a Method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/returnvalue.html)

for more details

Answer (score 0):

Try to do something like:

```
public static Student processStudentData(String[] a) {
    System.out.println("Running Test 2a:");
    if (a[1].equals("ADD")) {
        Student student2 = new Student(a[2], a[3], a[4], a[5]);
        return student2;
    }
    return null;
}
```

and don't forget to handle the NullPointerException.